Is there flux that doesn't brown under heat?
Adding flux (MG8341) to rework a component is resulting in ugly brown stains as shown in the picture below; this is a flexible circuit board with white cover-lay. The flux started to turn brown add about to 220C and this never got above 250C during the hot-plate work.
The WLCSP component works fine, so this is purely a cosmetic issue, which is perhaps exaggerated by the white background. Maybe we can clean the boards, but I would like to avoid that.
Is there a flux that remains clear after activating?


PCBAs are washed after PnP assembly and reflow.

Typically you'd just wash this off; 70% (not 99%) isopropanol will get it pretty easily, maybe acetone for stubborn bits (though be careful as that might dissolve some soldermask)

Use flux remover... Also if you want the best results green is the best silkscreen to work with, the other's don't work as well (I suspect for not being as widely used and tested.

Btw I've encountered flux that would look just fine during soldering but then during washing with water, it reacted with something in the water (was plain water from the faucet, not distilled) and left white residue all over the board. Didn't seem conductive but looked bad. So just because something looks fine after soldering doesn't mean it will look fine after washing, or after getting used in the field for that matter.

It's usually called "crystal" flux, though that might just be me remembering a brand name. Usually no-clean, for obvious reasons.
